# VBA Conditional Formatting - xlExpression - Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA, and I have searched online but have yet not succeeded and would like to ask kindly for your support. I would like to create an Excel Macro which turns cell entries red, when they do not meet a specific set of conditions (VAT Format).

My research indicates that the following should VBA code could work:

```
Set condition1 = rng.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, Formula1: "XXX")
Defining and setting the format to be applied for each condition
   With condition1
    .Font.Color = vbBlue
    .Font.Bold = True
   End With
```

I have written the conditional formatting code here:

```
=OR(AND(LEFT(B10,2)="CZ",OR(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,8))),ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,10))),ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,9)))),OR(LEN(B10)=10,LEN(B10)=11,LEN(B10)=12)),AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(3))),MID(B10,12,1)=".",ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(B10,9,3))),MID(B10,8,1)=".",ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(B10,5,3))),MID(B10,4,1)="-",LEFT(B10,3)="CHE",LEN(B10)=15),AND(LEFT(B10,2)="BG",OR(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,9))),ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,10)))),OR(LEN(B10)=11,LEN(B10)=12)),AND(LEFT(B10,2)="BE",ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,10))),LEN(B10)=12),AND(LEFT(B10,3)="ATU",ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,8))),LEN(B10)=11),AND(LEFT(B10,2)="DE",ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,9))),LEN(B10)=11),OR(AND(LEN(B10)=9,ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,8))),LEFT(B10,1)="X"),AND(LEN(B10)=9,ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(B10,8))),RIGHT(B10,1)="X"),AND(LEN(B10)=9,LEFT(B10,1)="X",RIGHT(B10,1)="X",ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(B10,2,7))))),AND(LEFT(B10,2)="EL",ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,9))),LEN(B10)=11),AND(LEFT(B10,2)="EE",ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,9))),LEN(B10)=11),AND(LEFT(B10,2)="DK",ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,8))),LEN(B10)=10),AND(LEFT(B10,2)="HR",ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,11))),LEN(B10)=13),AND(LEFT(B10,2)="GB",ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,9))),LEN(B10)=11),OR(AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,9))),NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(B10,3,1)))),LEFT(B10,2)="FR",LEN(B10)=13),AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,9))),NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(B10,4)))),LEFT(B10,2)="FR",LEN(B10)=13),AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,10))),NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(B10,3)))),LEFT(B10,2)="FR",LEN(B10)=13),AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(11))),LEFT(B10,2)="FR",LEN(B10)=13)),AND(LEFT(B10,2)="FI",ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,8))),LEN(B10)=10),AND(LEN(B10)=14,LEFT(B10,2)="NO",ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(B10,3,9))),RIGHT(B10,3)="MVA"),AND(LEN(B10)=14,LEFT(B10,2)="NL",ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(B10,3,9))),MID(B10,12,1)="B",ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,2)))),AND(LEFT(B10,2)="LU",ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,8))),LEN(B10)=10),AND(LEFT(B10,2)="IT",ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,11))),LEN(B10)=13),AND(LEFT(B10,2)="IL",ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,8))),ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,8)))),OR(AND(NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,2)))),ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(B10,7))),LEN(B10)=9),AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(B10,3,4))),ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(B10,1))),NOT(ISNUMBER(RIGHT(B10,1))),NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(B10,2,0)))),LEN(B10)=8),AND(NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,1)))),ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(B10,7))),LEN(B10)=8)),AND(LEFT(B10,2)="HU",ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,8))),LEN(B10)=10),AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,8))),LEFT(B10,2)="MT",LEN(B10)=10),OR(AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(12))),LEFT(B10,2)="LT",LEN(B10)=14),AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,9))),LEFT(B10,2)="LT",LEN(B10)=11)),AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,11))),LEFT(B10,2)="LV",LEN(B10)=13),AND(NOT(ISNUMBER(RIGHT(B10,1))),ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(B10,3,8))),LEFT(B10,2)="CY",LEN(B10)=11),AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,10))),LEFT(B10,2)="SK",LEN(B10)=12),AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,7))),LEFT(B10,2)="SI",LEN(B10)=10),AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,10))),LEFT(B10,2)="SE",LEN(B10)=14),OR(AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,2))),LEFT(B10,2)="RO",LEN(B10)=4),AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,3))),LEFT(B10,2)="RO",LEN(B10)=5),AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,4))),LEFT(B10,2)="RO",LEN(B10)=6),AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,5))),LEFT(B10,2)="RO",LEN(B10)=7),AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,6))),LEFT(B10,2)="RO",LEN(B10)=8),AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,7))),LEFT(B10,2)="RO",LEN(B10)=9),AND(LEN(B10)=10,LEFT(B10,2)="RO",ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,8)))),AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,9))),LEFT(B10,2)="RO",LEN(B10)=11),AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(B10,10))),LEFT(B10,2)="RO",LEN(B10)=12)),AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(B10,3,9))),LEFT(B10,2)="PT",LEN(B10)=11),AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(B10,3,10))),LEFT(B10,2)="PL",LEN(B10)=12))
```

How can I incorporate my conditions into the VBA code with conditional formatting turning cell entries red if they do not meet the above conditions?

Your support would be highly appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: That's a really huge formula. Does it work properly if you do it manually? Does your vba code rise any error? Can you explain better what does your formula do? It's really huge to read.

Comment: What about adding some helper columns as intermediate steps and then having a final helper column that is tested by the format condition

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Regarding your questions: 
1) It does work when I do it manually. 
2) For the VBA code, I do not know since I have not written it.

Comment: Let me give some more details, what should be happening: Users enter a VAT into a field. Each country in Europe has a defined VAT format. If the entry does not fit, the defined format of the country (e.g. starts with DE and has 9 characters) the cell turns red.

Comment: Hi, unrelated to the question, but you might be able to shorten some of your formula by using choose and match. I did an example of 3 countries: `=LEN(B15)=CHOOSE(MATCH(LEFT(B15,2);{"PL","DE","NO"},0),10,12,13)` here code starting with PL must have length 10, DE must have length 12 and NO must have length 13.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to modify the format of a cell: conditional formatting and VBA.

Using VBA, you write a macro like this:

```
IF InStr("CZ", Range("B10").Value) ...
THEN Range("..."). ' change the background colour
```

Using conditional formatting, you might apply a formula (or another rule) on a cell.

What you are doing, is writing a VBA macro where you, instead of colouring the cell, you want to apply conditional formatting, based on a complicated formula, which should then take care of the colouring.

Why are you making that combination?

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I think, I have approached this problem from the wrong angle. I though initially I could simply record a Macro and add the formula when it should turn the cells red. 

Let my try with the VBA code you recommended.